# routing ipv6 only in local wlan network (subnet)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6

I have a Gentoo Linux machine with got a V6 address via DHCP form my router. There is V4/V6 net. For DHCP I use dhcpcd with following conf:

```
duid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
noipv6rs

interface eth0
  ipv6rs
  ia_na

interface wlan0
  noipv6rs
  noipv4
  ipv6only
```

I try to create a router for internal wireless v6-only network.

I try to do the following:

1. Assign static address for wlan0 from v6 network:

   ```
   # ip addr show wlan0
   5: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
       link/ether 50:3e:aa:54:c2:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
       inet6 2001:470:xxxx:1000::1/64 scope global
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 fe80::b614:22ce:a510:66e3/64 scope link
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   ```
2. Add dnsmasq witch config:

   ```
   interface=wlan0
   listen-address=2001:470:xxxx:1000::1
   no-resolv
   server=2001:470:xxxx::1
   local=/subnet1/
   domain=subnet1
   dhcp-fqdn
   enable-ra
   dhcp-range=::100,::1ff, constructor:wlan0, ra-names, 64, 12h
   log-queries
   log-dhcp
   ```

Clients have got V6 addresses but no internet access. I can ping wlan0 clients from Gentoo machine but I can't ping global addresses from wlan0 and clients.

```
# ping6 google.com -I wlan0
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Should I add some static route for wlan0?

Current route table:

```
2001:470:yyyy:zzzz::/64 dev eth0 proto ra metric 204 mtu 1480 pref medium
anycast 2001:470:xxxx:: dev eth0 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
2001:470:xxxx::/64 dev eth0 proto ra metric 204 mtu 1480 pref medium
anycast 2001:470:xxxx:1000:: dev wlan0 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
2001:470:xxxx:1000::/64 dev eth0 metric 1 pref medium
2001:470:xxxx:1000::/64 dev wlan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev dummy0 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev eth0 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev wlan0 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev dummy0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev dummy0 metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eth0 metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev wlan0 metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::76d0:2bff:fed2:7b40 dev eth0 proto ra metric 204 mtu 1480 pref medium
```